# Trigger that collect the attribute value from one table and sum it to an attribute values of another table in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I join hereafter the script of two tables « poste_hta_bt » & « transf_hta_bt » and I would like to collect the inserted value of ‘puiss_kva’ with enum type from “transf_hta_bt” and sum it automatically by trigger with the attribute value ‘pui_kva’ in “poste_hta_bt”.
Since, we cannot cast directly enum type with integer, I create intermediate variables to work around this issue.
However, after insert, the trigger returns NULL value.
Any help is welcome.

```
DROP TYPE IF EXISTS puiss CASCADE;
CREATE TYPE puiss as enum ('100', '125', '150', 'NC');

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS poste_hta_bt CASCADE;
CREATE TABLE poste_hta_bt
(
    id_pt serial NOT NULL,
    code_pt VARCHAR(30) NULL,
    nom_pt VARCHAR(50) NULL,
    pui_kva smallint NULL,  -- to populate here the sum value with 'puiss_kva' attribute from transfo_hta_bt
    ...
)
;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS transfo_hta_bt CASCADE;
CREATE TABLE transfo_hta_bt
(
    id_tra serial NOT NULL,
    code_tra VARCHAR(30) NULL,
    code_pt VARCHAR(30) NULL,   -- FK referencing table poste_hta_bt
    puiss_kva puiss NULL,   -- enum type 'puiss'
    ...
)
;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION recap_transf() RETURNS TRIGGER 
language plpgsql AS 
$$
DECLARE
    puiss_int smallint;
    puiss_bool puiss;
    pui_bis smallint;

BEGIN
    IF (TG_OP = 'INSERT') THEN
        -- I can not directly cast enum type with integer, so I create puiss_bool & pui_int variables  
        SELECT NEW.puiss_kva INTO puiss_bool FROM transfo_hta_bt WHERE code_pt = NEW.code_pt;
        IF (puiss_bool = '100') THEN puiss_int := 100;
        ELSIF (puiss_bool = '125') THEN puiss_int := 125;
        ELSIF (puiss_bool = '150') THEN puiss_int := 150;
        ELSE puiss_int := 0;
        END IF;
        -- I collect the initial value of pui_kva from table poste_hta_bt
        SELECT pui_kva INTO pui_bis FROM poste_hta_bt WHERE poste_hta_bt.code_pt = NEW.code_pt;
        -- then I update puis_kva in table poste_hta_bt by the sum of puiss_int & pui_bis variables
        UPDATE poste_hta_bt SET pui_kva = (puiss_int + pui_bis) WHERE poste_hta_bt.code_pt = NEW.code_pt;
        RETURN NULL;
    ELSE
        RAISE WARNING 'Other action occurred: %, at %', TG_OP, now();
        RETURN NULL;
    END IF;
END;
$$
;

-- create trigger
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS recap_tr ON transfo_hta_bt;
CREATE TRIGGER recap_tr AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON transfo_hta_bt FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE recap_transf();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

COALESCE resolve my issue in order to avoid NULL value.
In the trigger function:
I delete the following (useless) :

```
SELECT pui_kva INTO pui_bis FROM poste_hta_bt WHERE poste_hta_bt.code_pt = NEW.code_pt;
```

and I replace

```
UPDATE poste_hta_bt SET pui_kva = (puiss_int + pui_bis) WHERE poste_hta_bt.code_pt = NEW.code_pt;
```

by

```
UPDATE poste_hta_bt SET pui_kva = COALESCE(pui_kva + puiss_int, puiss_int) WHERE poste_hta_bt.code_pt = NEW.code_pt;
```